# Symfony 1.4 embedRelation where clause

Tags: symfony-1.4, symfony-forms, doctrine-1.2

Is it possible to set a where clause on embedRelation?

```
$this->embedRelation('treatedStones');
```

I need to get the treatedStones where stone_free = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do this with `embedRelation`, but you can do manually as it's done in `sfFormDoctrine`.

```
$subForm = new sfForm();

// create a custom query e.g. in `TreatedStoneTable::queryFree($relatedId)` and
// a method to the class of `$this->getObject()` to retrieve free stones 
// e.g. `Class::getFreeTreatedStones()` to call the query
foreach ($this->getObject()->getFreeTreatedStones() as $index => $childObject)
{
  $form = new TreatedStoneForm($childObject);

  $subForm->embedForm($index, $form);
  $subForm->getWidgetSchema()->setLabel($index, (string) $childObject);
}

$this->embedForm('treated_stones', $subForm);
```

You can find further details about how forms work in the [docs](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms).

Comment: I was about posting the same answer!